# pyinstaller compiled .exe does nothing

Tags: python, tkinter, compilation, pyinstaller

Wrote a game and compiled it with pyinstaller.  An EXE file was created but when I go to run it, it thinks for 3-4 seconds and then it returns to command prompt.

Clicking from the folder in Windows does nothing.

No errors, nothing!  Do I need something in my code to allow this to run?  The only imports are tkinter and random.

Edit 1: tested a "hello world" script to see if there were issues with pyinstaller, it ran fine.

Comment: We can't fix code we can't see. Please read and follow the directions here: [mcve]

Comment: What do you get when you run your game before packaging it as an .exe file?

Comment: When you do your compile, add the debug flag, `-d` so that it tells you what is happening.

Comment: Gino Mempin, the game works perfectly running it from python.  No issues.  I will try the -d debug tonight when I get home from work.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that the post is older, but it may be useful for other member who may come across the similar problem.

I had created a script using Jupiter notebook and it creates ipynb file.
When I create an exe file using pyinstaller, the exe was doing nothing.

I resolved it by first converting ipynb file to py file using below command:
pyinstaller my_script.py

It will create the py file under same location.

Now, execute below command to create exe file:
pyinstaller my_script.py

It will create exe file under dist folder.

And it works.